# Find a class its .cs file in project

Tags: file-io, c#

How can I find the .cs file which contains a specified class in a project by code?

I imagine it could look like this:

```
string pathToFoo = ClassFileFinder.FindClassPath(typeof(Foo));
```

Comment: @ken2k the OP posted a pseudocode of what he is looking for

Comment: @ken2k This problem really goes beyond what I am used to. The only way I can think of is going through all the .cs files in the project and scanning through them as text, looking for the class definition that you would expect. But that is not very elegant. ANd I suspect not totally foolproof either.

Comment: right click that line, and select `Go to definition`

Comment: Actually what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: @Sayse I specified I need it to access it "by code".

Comment: Could you explain for which reason you need this functionality? Perhaps there is another method.

Comment: Then make a visual studio macro that does it, your cs files won't be there in the compiled exe, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel I am writing a server-client collaboration tool for a game engine where the projects are partially synchronized between both. I need the client to be able to request a specific class by name and the server needs to supply the .cs class file. Edit: And of course nothing is compiled to a .exe in the process, but the game editor could call the pseudocode I posted.

Comment: i would suggest having a class folder containing your classes and then  on client request calling your     className + ".cs" file 
in this folder, i dont' know if it can help, or if it's possible in your situation

Comment: @losSebos I was thinking in this direction. However it depends on the user (server administrator) following instructions carefully and it limits the way in which the user can structure his project as well (for example cannot have partial classes and cannot have multiple classes in one file). A full text search through all .cs files would support partial classes and multi-class files, but is not ideal (slow). Edit: I suspect it is the only viable option, though.

Comment: 'server-client collaboration tool'? You mean some kind of source control system? What is the problem with using, say, Git or Mercurial?

Comment: It has functionality specific to the editor/engine that Git lacks. Git would handle this particular issue (I'd rather handle it myself within the tool though).

Comment: I have written and tested a ClassFileFinder class based on the idea to look through the text of the project literally. I can't post it yet because need to wait 10 hours. Will provide the class when possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written and tested the class based on some ideas I had and in found in the comments. It works reasonably fast and I haven't found any problems with it so far.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public static class ClassFileFinder
{
static List<string> classFiles;

public static ClassFileDetails FindClassFile(System.Type t)
{
    return FindClassFile(t.Name);
}

public static ClassFileDetails FindClassFile(string className)
{
    ClassFileDetails details = DatabaseLink.GetClassFileDetails(className);
    if (details == null)
    {
        //Lookup class name in file names
        classFiles = new List<string>();
        FindAllScriptFiles(Application.dataPath);
        Debug.Log(classFiles.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < classFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            if (classFiles[i].Contains(className))
            {
                details = new ClassFileDetails(className, classFiles[i],    File.GetLastAccessTimeUtc(classFiles[i]));
            }
        }
        //Lookup class name in the class file text 
        if (details == null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < classFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                string codeFile = File.ReadAllText(classFiles[i]);
                if (codeFile.Contains("class " + className))
                {
                    details = new ClassFileDetails(className, classFiles[i], File.GetLastAccessTimeUtc(classFiles[i]));
                }
            }
        }
        if (details == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Failed to lookup class file for class " + className);
        }
        return details;
    }
    else
    {
        return details;
    }
}

     static void FindAllScriptFiles(string startDir)
    {
   try
   {
       foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(startDir))
       {
           if (file.Contains(".cs") || file.Contains(".js"))
               classFiles.Add(file);
       }
       foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(startDir))
       {
           FindAllScriptFiles(dir);
       }
   }
   catch (System.Exception ex)
   {
       Debug.Log(ex.Message);
   }
   }
}

public class ClassFileDetails
{
public int OID { get; set; }
public string className { get; set; }
[Sqo.Attributes.UniqueConstraint]
public string path { get; set; }
public System.DateTime updateTime { get; set; }

internal ClassFileDetails()
{ }
internal ClassFileDetails(string setClassName, string setPath, System.DateTime setUpdateTime)
{
    className = setClassName;
    path = setPath;
    updateTime = setUpdateTime;

    DatabaseLink.StoreClassFileDetails(this);
}
```

}

Comment: Just had an idea that one might want to exclude the possibility that the class name is found in a commented line

Answer (score 0):

It does not make any sense what you are trying to do. You wont have any .cs file in compiled executable at the end.

Moreover, you may have different class filenames than class identifers declared in class definitions so I doubt simple file search will also not guarantee finding file in source code. So IMO its not possible.

Comment: 1) There is no compiled executable 2) Yes a file search is problematic. It may still be possible to look through the file contents and not just the names but it may become a bit of a heavy search.

Comment: @JulesVos, about remark (1), what output you get after building (compiling) the project. Its .dll or .exe. Your class file after compilation will be part of this output (not anymore .cs file)

Comment: One way to make the search less heavy would be to enforce a workflow by which every Class was in a C# file named the same as the class - which is generally a good thing anyway. You'd still probably have the classes distributed throughout a folder structure but the search would be easy.

Comment: The code is compiled by the editor application mentioned to run within the editor. In the process I think it compiles it to some internal assemblies while leaving the .cs files intact.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to modify the file at runtime? That's not a very good idea and a huge security concern. You could always try to use System.Reflector to see the contents of the class at runtime. Also, if you're wanting to add a function to a class that is in a library, you can use an extension method.

Comment: Why do you think I want to modify any files? Much less at runtime? (there is no runtime, this is for an editor plugin)

Comment: I see, well there was no context to the question, so I made a guess. You can create the ClassFileFinder class pretty easily. Make it find the root folder for you .cs files. You're best bet is to then parse every file name until it matches the class name.

Comment: Does not work for multi-class files and partial classes. But easy enough to go through the text as well, then I think all possibilities for problems are sealed

Comment: Oh yeah, partial classes might be tough, but if you use a good naming convention it might work. I like to name my partial classes the name of the main class plus a .whatTheClassDoes  so "Player.Shoot.cs". If you had that kind of structure, then you could ignore the files with two periods, or you could even store all of the related class file paths together. As for multi-class files, Those are usually bad, but of course some nested classes and stuff is unavoidable for large projects. You could do a similar naming convention for classes in the same file so that the parser knows it has multiple.