# Is there a way to find the path to class file present in some other project ( not the startup project) using c#?

Tags: c#

I know the class name. Now I want to know the path of this class present in the current working solution. 
Eg: I have a solution in visual studio which contains 5 projects- A, B, C, D, E. C is my startup project. I know the class "abc.cs" which can be present in any of these 5 projects. 
Is there a way to find the path to this class file using c#?

I have tried this:

```
var fileName= @"abc.cs";
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filename);
```

This throws exception that file does not exist, as it looks into current working directory.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to find the path to the class file so that I can parse the file.

Comment: You could parse the solution file to get the list of projects, then parse the csproj files to get a list of files in these projects. The path of the found file will normally be a relative path (relative to the directory where the csproj file is).

Comment: What if someone else runs this program on another computer, there will be no .cs. file?

Comment: Tagged with “reflection” but you are asking about path to cs file... Very confusing. What do you mean “parse the file”?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find path to .cs file by its type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960071/how-to-find-path-to-cs-file-by-its-type-in-c-sharp) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697865/find-a-class-its-cs-file-in-project

Comment: Not sure what you trying to do here: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you generate pdb files for your assemblies. Otherwise, you might need to "redo Reflector", and the answer would be much longer.

If all projects are under your control, you can:

```
class A
{
    //......
    static readonly string FilePath;
    //......

    static A()
    {
        FilePath = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetFileName(); 
    }
}
```

Starting from 4.5, you can also do:

```
class A
{
    //......
    static readonly string FilePath;
    //......

    static A([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",)
    {
        FilePath = sourceFilePath;
    }
}
```

If the projects are not under your control, there are options, but they require a lot more work.