# How can I get the source file-path of a class declaration?

Tags: c#, reflection, file-io

Similar to this question: [Find a class its .cs file in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697865/find-a-class-its-cs-file-in-project) - did not find an up-to-date example from this thread.

**Example:**

- I have a class named `ExampleClass1` located in: `Project/Example/ExampleClass.cs`
- This source file can be generated by code or not.
- The main program saves all generated source files, and needs to know if one of the classes have been moved to another directory manually. If it has, the list should be updated with the new path.
- The paths are needed in order to handle the source files (delete, move, etc) from the main program.

**In the main script I would like to know the path of the source file where the class (type) is declared.**

Pseudocode:

```
string filePath = "Project/Example/ExampleClass1.cs"
string className = "ExampleClass1"
if (!File.Exists(currentFilePath)) //If it does not exist, check if it exists in a different path
{
    string className = "ExampleClass1"; //could also be a Type instead of string
    filePath = GetPathOfType(className); //returns "Project/Example/ExampleClass.cs"
}
```

Comment: Generally not possible, because the source files are not part of the compiled code. There might be work-arounds that can be applied to your specific situation, but for that we'd need more context information. Please describe in more detail what exactly you are trying to do. Also: how do you plan to deploy the application to users and how do you plan to deploy the source files to user machines?

Comment: The source files are generated by using CodeDom to compile data into .cs files into a specific root folder. The user can edit data in the program which will then modify the source file by rewriting the file. The user can then make use of the data from the source file in other non-generated source files in the same assembly. **The reason I want the path of the generated class is in the rare case that the source file has moved into a different directory, or changed file-name.** In this case, I would like the program to find it, so that it still can be modified after the change.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it is naturally vulnerable to errors and user damage. The only real way to avoid these things, is to essentially 'clone' the source files for the user to modify as they please, but still compile the actual program down to an executable program.